# Gimp giving me "Failed to load module "atk-bridge" "canberra-gtk-module"

Tags: drivers, libraries, gimp

When i run:

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP//stable
```

I get

```
Gtk-Message: 17:30:34.696: Failed to load module "atk-bridge"
Gtk-Message: 17:30:34.754: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

But GIMP does open, and when i try to install those using:

```
sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

It says i already have the newest version, but i don't like that error message haha. What i do?

Edit: Also did

```
sudo apt-get install libatk-adaptor:i386
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```